# Obter apenas o valor final do banco

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Estou a usar o *php* com *pdo* para fazer consultas num banco de dados em `postgress`.

Existe alguma forma de que, quando faça a `query`, mostre o resultado sem ter que meter o nome da tabela, uma vez que o select é unico?

```
select distinct a as origem 
 from b union select distinct  as dest form b
```

php

```
for ($x = 0; $x < $stmt->rowCount(); $x++) {
    $n[] = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
```

Esta forma se coloca o nome da tabela, sei que se fizer `$row['origem']` funciona mas pode haver o `dest` também.

Comment: Não entendi, onde vc n quer informar o nome da tabela? se não informar o nome como o banco vai saber em qual tabela vc quer fazer a pesquisa.

Comment: Você quer não informar o nome da tabela ou do campo? Porque no caso pelo que entendi, o seu "$row['origem']", "origem" não é o nome da tabela, e sim o apelido dado ao campo

Comment: Não sei se é isto mas lemdoas tabelas de metadados http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/catalogs.html montar sqls dinâmicos , seria esta a ideia ?